# operator overloading error no match operator <<

Tags: c++

i am learning operator overloading in C++ i created a program to overload the increment operator both postfix and prefix

it shows error no match for operator<<

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class counter
{
    unsigned int countx;
public:
    counter(): countx(0)
    {}
    counter (int c) : countx(c)
    {}
    unsigned int get_count() const
    {
        return countx;
    }
    counter operator ++ ()
    {
        return counter(++countx);
    }
    counter operator ++ (int)
    {
        return counter(countx++);
    }
};

int main()
{
    counter c1, c2;
    cout<<endl<<"c1 : "<<c1.get_count;
    cout<<endl<<"c2 : "<<c2.get_count;

    ++c1;
    c2 = ++c1;
    cout<<endl<<"c1 : "<<c1.get_count;
    cout<<endl<<"c2 : "<<c1.get_count;

    c2= c1++;
    cout<<endl<<"c1 : "<<c1.get_count;
    cout<<endl<<"c2 : "<<c2.get_count;

    return 0;
}
```

could you please suggest something to overcome this and also explain why this error occurs?

Comment: You need to call the functions. `c1.get_count` must be `c1.get_count()`.

Comment: oh sorry i had not even reviewed the code. by the way thanks for telling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My compiler (llvm) says:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
    cout<<endl<<"c1 : "<<c1.get_count;
                         ~~~^~~~~~~~~
                                     ()
```

that suggests you to make a call:

```
cout<<endl<<"c1 : "<<c1.get_count();
```

Comment: hey what's the difference between ```cin.getline(str,size)``` and ```getline(cin,str)```

Comment: sorry i cannot because stackoverflow says you have exceeded your question limit please do answer in comments.